# AXLSX X-Axis Scaling

Tags: ruby, linechart, axlsx

Made an account just for this, because I really can't figure this one out using the AXLSX gem. I have a line chart generated already with labels, but I want to space them out evenly using the MAX value rounded up to the nearest 10,000th for 9 points.

The example I attached has 120,152 as the highest values, so I want to set the MAX as 130,000, and have even intervals for each point leading up to it (0, 12k, 24k, 36k, for example).

How would I be able to customize the labels to follow this scheme using the AXLSX gem?

[Picture of my Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBJdh.png)

Thanks!

Comment: can you please edit your post with your code with enough to reproduce?

Comment: @@compAry.each_with_index do |data,index|
         @dbChart.add_series :data => @wb.sheet_by_name("DBsim Source" + index.to_s)["D3:M3"], :labels => @wb.sheet_by_name("DBsim Source" + index.to_s)["D2:M2"], :title => "Source" + index.to_s, :show_marker => true
        end
        


I basically have 2 individual sheets stored in a global array called @@compAry. I'm cycling through both sheets and making a new series using the "IOPS" data as my labels (which is what I want to change)

P.S - I dont know how to format within this box to make it look cleaner, so sorry about that